# Добавление GET запросов к уже существующим

Tags: php, html

Имеется ссылка: домен/index.php?id=42
Как с помощью формы добавить еще GET запрос, не убирая уже имеющуюся?
В итоге должно получится так: /index.php?id=42&number=3
Проблема в том, что форма убирает id и получется так: /index.php?number=3
Форма:

```
<form action="#" method="_GET">
<select name="number">
<?php
for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
    echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Выбрать">
</form>
```

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="id" value=42">

Comment: @splash58 thanks

Answer (score 0):

Самый тупой и простой способ

```
<form action="#" method="_GET">
<input name="id" value="<?echo @$_GET['id']?>" style="display:none">
<select name="number">
<?php
for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
    echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Выбрать">
</form>
```